# rails file_field not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine, uppy

I would like to make my app upload multiple files with Shrine, but [one doc](https://shrinerb.com/docs/multiple-files#3-create-the-view) suggests two `file_field`s whereas the [other](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/wiki/Adding-Direct-App-Uploads#5-form) suggests only one. After posting a question to their discourse forum, it was suggested that I hide the one named `files[]`. Whether I do this or not, the first `file_field` always fails to render. Why does this field not display?

```
<%= form_for @item, html: { enctype: "multipart/form-data" } do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :photos do |i| %>
  <%= i.label :image %>
  <%= i.hidden_field :image, value: i.object.cached_photos_data, class: "upload-data" %>
  <%= i.file_field :image, class: "upload-file" %> /// why is this not rendering?
 <% end %>
 <%= file_field_tag "files[]", multiple: true %> // what purpose does this one serve?
 
 <%= f.text_field :title %>
      
 <%= f.submit "Submit" %>    
<% end %>
```

Models:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :photos, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
 include ImagesUploader::Attachment(:image)
 belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
 validates_presence_of :image
end
```

Controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @item = current_user.items.new
 end

 def create
  @item = current_user.items.create(item_params)
  @item.save
 end

 private
 def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:title, photos_attributes: { image: [] })
 end
end
```

Comment: In 2020 active_storage is recommended for uploading files in Ruby on Rails https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#

Comment: @Yshmarov Active Storage is terrible once you start working with it. it generates versions on the fly (why anyone would want to do this in production is beyond me), it gives less control over storage in S3, and it performs unnecessary db queries. it's not good. the professional recommendation everywhere is to go for shrine.

Answer (score 1):

Read the first link carefully: It says that the single field (`i.file_field :image`) is used to display existing images (which is why it's wrapped in `f.fields_for :photos` in the example) and the multiple field (`file_field_tag "files[]", multiple: true`) is used to upload new files. So if your `@item` doesn't have an `:image`, then the field isn't shown.

Let me know if this needs any further clarification – happy to help!

Comment: also you can `build` the relationship however many time in your controller. So in the new action you can do `3.times { @item.photos.build }` and that will start the relationship and allow the fields to show in the form